# Express not serving Gzipped assets

Tags: javascript, express, gzip

I have an express app, which hosts a JS application, html page and bundled styles.

I am applying a CSP to my Express app, however it is now not serving any gzipped assets and I am at a loss why.

Express

```
const express = require('express');
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const commonPath = require('../config/common-paths');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const POLICY_NONE = ["'none'"];
const POLICY_SELF = ["'self'"];

app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy({ policy: 'same-origin' }));
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      connectSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      fontSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      imgSrc: POLICY_SELF.concat(['blob:', 'data:']),
      manifestSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      mediaSrc: POLICY_SELF.concat(['*.nodediggity.com']),
      objectSrc: POLICY_NONE,
      scriptSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      styleSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      workerSrc: POLICY_SELF,
      formAction: POLICY_SELF,
      frameAncestors: POLICY_NONE,
      blockAllMixedContent: true,
      upgradeInsecureRequests: false,
    },
  })
);

app.options('*', cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 })); // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204

app.use(
  '/',
  expressStaticGzip(commonPath.outputPath, { indexFromEmptyFile: false })
);


app.get('/healthz', (_, res) => res.send('OK'));
app.get('*', (_, res) => res.sendFile(commonPath.outputPath + '/index.html'));

const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.SERVER_HOST || 'localhost';

app.listen(PORT);
console.log(`API started on ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

Webpack build config

```
const commonPaths = require('../common-paths');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: commonPaths.srcPath,
  entry: {
    signal: ['babel-polyfill', './signal/app'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(jsx?)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['babel-loader'] },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Web App',
      template: commonPaths.projectRoot + '/public/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'static/[name].[hash].min.css',
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.(j|cs)s$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      deleteOriginalAssets: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod',
    }),
  ],
};
```

My index.html loads, however no styles or js are applied and the console has the following error

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/static/signal.ab8a8afea9d967e4bd23.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

It is the same for the bundled JS file. If I turn off gzip then it works perfect.

Folder structure

[Folder Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exvQ1.png)

What is odd, is if I request the css file in the browser, and attach the `.gz` extension, the file downloads. So I am confident the folder structure is ok, as this also works if I just remove gzip compression.

Common Paths

```
const path = require('path');
const PROJECT_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: PROJECT_ROOT,
  serverPath: path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'server'),
  srcPath: path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src'),
  appPath: path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src/app'),
  signalPath: path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src/signal'),
  outputPath: path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'dist'),
};
```

Common-paths.js is located in the config folder.

Comment: any comments present in your css?

Comment: also please specify folder structure where file is present and line where it is refernced

Comment: No, no comments in the css

Comment: The folder structure is ```dist > index.html > static > css and js assets in gzip form```

Comment: index.html is folder name?

Comment: Sorry no, index.html is in the dist, one moment and I will update my question with a proper explanation of the folder structure

Comment: add value of commonPath.outputPath as well

Comment: I have added more to my question

Comment: 2 more posible places of error: 1) value of commonPath.outputPath 2) how line is written where css is referenced in html. please post that as well

Comment: Just as a sidenote, it's a best practice to actually *not* put common output stuff like this into your Node app, but instead let your reverse proxy (eg Apache or NGINX) handle it.  Compression, caching, etc are all activities they do w/ simple configuration, and probably better than node will.

Comment: ```commonPath.outputPath``` is outputting ```/Users/dev-acct/Code/Apps/signal-webapp/dist```

Comment: and line where css is referenced has type and / in front of it?

Comment: Yes, the CSS, which is referenced in my JS application, is pulled in like this

```import './css/app.css';
import './css/about.css';
import './css/controls.css';```
Within the ```app.js``` file